# Use useSelect/useDispatch instead of withSelect/withDispatch

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor

I've built a Featured Gallery component for Gutenberg that uses the `withSelect` and `withDispatch` higher order components to store the selected images in a meta field.
I'm wondering if this code can be converted to use the `useSelect` and `useDispatch` hooks instead to simplify it. Is it possible? I tried to do it myself reading the almost useless Gutenberg docs with no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const {
    BaseControl,
    Button
} = wp.components;
const { compose } = wp.compose;
const { withSelect, withDispatch } = wp.data;
const { MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck }  = wp.blockEditor;

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import FeaturedGalleryImage from './featured-gallery-image';

const ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES = [ 'image' ];

function FeaturedGallery( {
    featuredGalleryIds,
    onUpdateGallery,
    onClearGallery,
    noticeUI,
} ) {
    const instructions = (
        <p>
            { __(
                'To edit the featured gallery, you need permission to upload media.', 'my-featured-gallery'
            ) }
        </p>
    );

    const hasImages = !! featuredGalleryIds.length;

    return (
        <BaseControl
            className="my-featured-gallery"
        >
            { noticeUI }
            <div className="editor-post-featured-gallery">
                <div className="editor-post-featured-gallery__container">
                    { hasImages && (
                        <ul className="featured-gallery-grid">
                            { featuredGalleryIds.map( ( img ) => (
                                <li key={ img } tabIndex={0}>
                                    <FeaturedGalleryImage
                                        id={ img }
                                    />
                                </li>
                            ) ) }
                        </ul>
                    ) }
                </div>
                <MediaUploadCheck fallback={ instructions }>
                    <MediaUpload
                        title={ __( 'Featured gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' ) }
                        multiple
                        gallery
                        addToGallery={ hasImages }
                        onSelect={ onUpdateGallery }
                        allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
                        value={ hasImages ? featuredGalleryIds : [] }
                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                                <Button
                                    className={
                                        hasImages
                                            ? 'editor-post-featured-gallery__edit'
                                            : 'editor-post-featured-gallery__add'
                                    }
                                    onClick={ open }
                                    isSecondary
                                >
                                    {
                                        hasImages
                                            ? __( 'Edit gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                                            : __( 'Add to gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                                    }
                                </Button>
                        ) }
                    />
                </MediaUploadCheck>                
                { hasImages && (
                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                        <Button onClick={ onClearGallery } isLink isDestructive>
                            { 
                                __( 'Clear gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                            }
                        </Button>
                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                ) }
            </div>
        </BaseControl>            
    );
}

const applyWithSelect = withSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getPostType } = select( 'core' );
    const { getCurrentPostId, getEditedPostAttribute } = select(
        'core/editor'
    );
    const meta = getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' );
    const featuredGalleryIds = meta._featured_gallery;
    
    return {
        currentPostId: getCurrentPostId(),
        postType: getPostType( getEditedPostAttribute( 'type' ) ),
        featuredGalleryIds,
    };
} );

const applyWithDispatch = withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => {
        const { editPost } = dispatch( 'core/editor' );
        return {
            onUpdateGallery( images ) {
                const items = images.map( ( item ) => item.id );
                const meta = { _featured_gallery: items };
                editPost( { meta } );
            },
            onClearGallery() {
                const meta = { _featured_gallery: [] };
                editPost( { meta } );
            }
        };
    }
);

export default compose(
    applyWithSelect,
    applyWithDispatch,
)( FeaturedGallery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head against Gutenberg's wall for a few hours, I came up with something that seems to work. It uses the `useSelect` and `useEntityProp` hooks instead of the `withSelect` and `withDispatch` HOCs. The truth is that using hooks makes the code simpler and easier to understand.

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const {
    BaseControl,
    Button
} = wp.components;
const { useSelect } = wp.data;
const { useEntityProp } = wp.coreData;
const { MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck }  = wp.blockEditor;

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */

import FeaturedGalleryImage from './featured-gallery-image';

const ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES = [ 'image' ];

function FeaturedGallery( {
    noticeUI,
} ) {
    const instructions = (
        <p>
            { __(
                'To edit the featured gallery, you need permission to upload media.', 'my-featured-gallery'
            ) }
        </p>
    );

    const postType = useSelect(
        ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
        []
    );

    const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp(
        'postType',
        postType,
        'meta'
    );

    const featuredGalleryIds = meta['_featured_gallery'];
    const hasImages = !! featuredGalleryIds.length;

    function onUpdateGallery( images ) {
        const items = images.map( ( item ) => item.id );
        setMeta( { ...meta, '_featured_gallery': items } );
    }

    function onClearGallery() {
        setMeta( { ...meta, '_featured_gallery': [] } );
    }

    return (
        <BaseControl
            className="my-featured-gallery"
        >
            { noticeUI }
            <div className="editor-post-featured-gallery">
                <div className="editor-post-featured-gallery__container">
                    { hasImages && (
                        <ul className="featured-gallery-grid">
                            { featuredGalleryIds.map( ( img ) => (
                                <li key={ img } tabIndex={0}>
                                    <FeaturedGalleryImage
                                        id={ img }
                                    />
                                </li>
                            ) ) }
                        </ul>
                    ) }
                </div>
                <MediaUploadCheck fallback={ instructions }>
                    <MediaUpload
                        title={ __( 'Featured gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' ) }
                        multiple
                        gallery
                        addToGallery={ hasImages }
                        onSelect={ onUpdateGallery }
                        allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
                        value={ hasImages ? featuredGalleryIds : [] }
                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                                <Button
                                    className={
                                        hasImages
                                            ? 'editor-post-featured-gallery__edit'
                                            : 'editor-post-featured-gallery__add'
                                    }
                                    onClick={ open }
                                    isSecondary
                                >
                                    {
                                        hasImages
                                            ? __( 'Edit gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                                            : __( 'Add to gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                                    }
                                </Button>
                        ) }
                    />
                </MediaUploadCheck>                
                { hasImages && (
                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                        <Button onClick={ onClearGallery } isLink isDestructive>
                            { 
                                __( 'Clear gallery', 'my-featured-gallery' )
                            }
                        </Button>
                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                ) }
            </div>
        </BaseControl>            
    );
}

export default FeaturedGallery;
```